# how to call ajax for pagedList in asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using pagedList it is working but i need to have an ajax call to bring a new page i don't know how to do.

```
public ActionResult ApplicantsRecord(int page =1)
    {
        List<ApplicantsRecord> ar = new List<ApplicantsRecord>();
        ApplicantsRecord a = new ApplicantsRecord();
        List<ApplicantsRecordDetailViewModel> apvmlist = new List<ApplicantsRecordDetailViewModel>();
        ApplicantsRecordDetailViewModel apvm = new ApplicantsRecordDetailViewModel();
        //ar = db.ApplicantsRecords.ToList();
        var groupedAR = db.ApplicantsRecords.GroupBy(x => x.SessionId)
                                .Select(y => new
                                {
                                    SessionId = y.Key,
                                    ApplicationsRecords = y.FirstOrDefault(),
                                }).ToList().OrderByDescending(x => x.ApplicationsRecords.LoginDate);
        foreach (var i in groupedAR)
        {
            ar.Add(i.ApplicationsRecords);
        }         
        if(Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            return PartialView("_ApplicantsRecord", ar.ToPagedList(page, 10));
        }
        return View(ar.ToPagedList(page, 10));
    }
```

and here is the view code

```
<div id="pagerecord">    
@Html.Partial("_ApplicantsRecord");
</div>    
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">    
        $(document).ready(function () {    
          var getpage = function () {
             var $a = $(this);
             var options = {
                url: $a.attr("href"),
                type: "get"
            };
            $.ajax(options).done(function (data) {
                var target = $a.parents("div.pagedList").attr("next");
                $(target).replaceWith(data);
            });
            return false;
         };

        $('main-conten').on('click', '.pagedList', getpage)
    });
</script>
```

and here is the partial view

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="220" align="center">                    
                <div class="pagedList" data-back-btn-text="next">
                    @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("ApplicantsRecord", new { page }),
         PagedListRenderOptions.MinimalWithItemCountText)
                </div>
        </th>
        @*<th width="220" align="center">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserName)</th>
            <th width="220" align="center">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LoginDate)</th>
            <th width="220" align="center">Details</th>*@
    </tr>
</thead>
```

Comment: Q. Is `main-conten` the correct name (e.g. is it really not `main-content`)?

Comment: Your delegated click handler is responding to `.pagedList` clicks and not the anchors within it, so your `$(a) = $(this)` is not the anchor so you are not getting the `href`. Do a save-as from your browser, to show us the client-side HTML and it will be easy to fix.

Comment: i changed it to main-content but didn't worked

Comment: can you please send me all the new code for view and partial view

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this already?

```
var getpage = function () {
        var $a = $(this);

        $.ajax({
             url: $a.attr("href"),
             type: "get",
             success: function(data) {

                 var target = $a.parents("div.pagedList").attr("next");
                 $(target).replaceWith(data);

             }, 
             error: function() {
                  return false;
             }
        });

    };
```

Next what you need tot do is:

Try to figure out if the data you are receiving is really the data you are expecting.
See if you do not enter the error function.

Comment: This was better suited to a comment. You have only replaced a `promise`-based Ajax version with the parameterized version without effectively changing anything.

Comment: yup i tried but it was not working i have only one action both for the first view and for calling ajax is it ok or i m doing wrong

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie 


  now ajax is working but it remains on the same page

Comment: @TreuBlueAssie I would have posted it in a comment if the comment would make code readable. And As I understand the ajax does work now, so it was not a total loss.

Comment: @Khan Engineer I normally don't use a C# backend In the promise / success method you can do anything you would like to do on the front-end. So from re-routing to another page to altering the dom, or running some other functionality. You're a smart man you will think of a way ;)

Comment: you can check my new post in that ajax is working but i need sm thing slse mentioned in that post please check and ans me there

Answer (score 0):

The first thing wrong is your selector is not a valid selector. `$('main-conten')` should probably be `$('#main-conten')` (assuming it is an element with an id of `main-conten`).

Secondly, you are using a delegated event handler, but listening for clicks on the `.pagedList` element and not the anchors within it:

```
$('main-conten').on('click', '.pagedList', getpage)
```

but inside the handler you are expecting the anchor to have been clicked as you are using:

```
var $a = $(this);
```

and

```
$a.attr("href")
```

**Try something like this:**

```
$(function () {
    // Listen for clicks on anchors inside the paging panel
    $('#main-conten').on('click', '.pagedList a', function () {
        var $a = $(this);
        var options = {
            url: $a.attr("href"),
            type: "get"
        };
        $.ajax(options).done(function (data) {
            // Do something with the returned data
            var target = $a.closest("div.pagedList").attr("next");
            $(target).replaceWith(data);
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

**Notes:**

- `$(function () {YOUR CODE HERE});` is just a handy shortcut for `$(document).ready(function(){});`
- Use `closest()` in preference to `parents()` where you only expect a single matching ancestor.

*If all this still does not work, please post your HTML output (not source) as saved from the browser.*

Comment: @Khan Engineer: Which part didn't you understand? If you want specifics, please provided a *save-as* of the HTML from the browser (not just the source). Then I can mockup something in a JSFiddle.

Comment: i did new code in that ajax is working but every time on click it brings a new page but i need the previous as well when clicked on previous and specific page when click on specific page number

Comment: @Khan Engineer: *if* you update your question with the latest code and *if* you add the page HTML requested, *then* I will spend more time looking at this. I am not psychic, so do not work with guesses :)